# Printing a html table with JS on window load

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, printing

I need to print the contents of a table element to a POS receipt printer, I am doing it like this:

```
    <?php
    private function message(){
    return '<!DOCTYPE html><html moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint><body style="padding:30px;">'
.'<table id="print-area" style="height: 501px; border:1px solid red;padding:1em;margin:0 0 1em" width="364" ><tr><td>example</td></tr></table></table>'
.'<p>&nbsp;</p></body> </html>'}
    ?>
```

What I am doing is that I am passing the return of that PHP function to a new function. Please ignore the php functions structure and logic, these are just an example of how I am doing this, I know that this might not be the best way to do this, but on what I really need help is on the JavaScript part. Why is it not printing and closing the new window?.

I need to print just the table and make it fit to the POS receipt page, without printing a whole blank space.... I have already tried with this version of the PrintReceipt function but it prints a lot of white space on the receipt.

```
    public function PrintReceipt($content) {

    echo"<!DOCTYPE html><script type='application/javascript'>
                    window.onload=function(){          
                        var myWindow = window.open('', 'MsgWindow', 'width=200,height=100');
                        myWindow.document.write('" . $content . "');
                        myWindow.print();
                        myWindow.close();              
                    }
    </script>";
}
```

Comment: I tested your js function and the piece of code provided in OP...it's works as expected on my env the ( used second version in OP)...may be the problem is somewhere else. You've to post more code for that

Comment: @NishanthMatha I am receiving this error when I run it on my side:
_TypeError: myWindow.frames.print_frame is undefined
 step4:5:29_ It is just opening the new window but not sending it to the printer.

Comment: I tested the second version of code

Comment: Yes, the problem with the second version of code (aka the _old one_) is that when I try to print that it just prints a big white space on the receipt and I want the table to fit the size of the receipt paper...

Comment: you seem to be using frames..can you post your `print_frame` code

Comment: I think that is the part that I am doing wrong, I do not really know what that part of the code does. I tried deleting it from my source but now I get the error. _ TypeError: myWindow.document.getElementById(...).contentWindow is undefined
_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using `frames` the there is no point in declaring the following lines:

```
myWindow.frames['print_frame'].document.title = document.title; 
myWindow.document.getElementById('print-area').contentWindow.print();
```

Which means that your 2nd attempt in OP is correct. If there's empty space then that's absolutely a `css` problem. If you want the table to occupy `100%` of the page width do:

`return '<table id="print-area" style="height: 100%; border:1px solid red;padding:1em;margin:0 0 1em" width="100%" ><tr><td>example</td></tr></table></table>';`

instead of

`return '<!DOCTYPE html><html moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint><body style="padding:30px;">'
.'<table id="print-area" style="height: 501px; border:1px solid red;padding:1em;margin:0 0 1em" width="364" ><tr><td>example</td></tr></table></table>'
.'<p>&nbsp;</p></body> </html>'}`

Comment: I tested your js function and the piece of code provided in OP...it's works as expected on my env...may be the problem is somewhere else. You've to post more code for that

Comment: Hi, this was just the right answer! I can deduce that it will work on a POS printer as it worked on  regular printer. Thank you for the help @Nishanth